# Is there an ASP MVC equivilent to JSTL tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jstl

Are there any libraries that support JSTL style coding in an ASP MVC view?

I much prefer

```
<c:forEach var="c" items="${Customers}">
  <c:out value="${c.Name}"/><br/ >
</c:forEach>
```

to

```
<% foreach(Customer c in customers) { %>
  <%= c.Name %><br/ >
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, [Spark](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark) is probably your friend on that one. Looks pretty similar in spirit.

```
<c:forEach var="c" items="${Customers}">
  <c:out value="${c.Name}"/><br/ >
</c:forEach>
```

becomes

```
<for each="var c in Customers">
  ${c.Name}<br/>
</for>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I know is the [Spark view engine](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark).

Answer (score 0):

The view engines which are closest to JSTL style coding are:

- [Spark View Engine](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark)
- [Sharp Tiles](http://www.sharptiles.org/)

From a JSTL prospective Sharp tiles would be the better in the sense of appliance and learning curve