# Can SparkView Engine create custom Tag?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Here  [Is there an ASP MVC equivilent to JSTL tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772634/is-there-an-asp-mvc-equivilent-to-jstl-tags) it is said that there is equivalent between jstl for loop and sparkview engine loop.

But beyond that can sparview allow to create custom tag without one digging into sparkview source code ie is it also a framework that is extensible without touching the core ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question exactly, but what I think you may be referring to is the Spark Bindings feature which allows you to create custom tags, and in the tag definitions you can perform any valid operation you would like.

Check out Spark Bindings here: http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/bindings